# Creating a temporary file in VB on Windows 7 PC

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, environment-variables

I have a VB program that creates a temporay PDF file then opens Outlook and attaches the file. I create the file in the application path (the location that the program is running from - normally C:\Program Files\ProgamName). This works fine in XP as it appears there are no crazy permission issues. However in Windows 7, the file does not appear. There are no errors, the file does not exist in that location.

I've changed the path to the root of C:\, however this doesn't work either. I suspect it's something to do with W7 virtualisation, so the question is where can I create a file that I can then access again?

I was trying to avoid creating it on a share on a server, but it's looking like this is the only place to put it as there doesn't seem to be many places a user can write files to in Windows 7.

Surely there must be a location that users can access (without being administrators) to create files. Don't even get me started on the fun I have had with the registry in W7!!!

Thanks

Patrick

Comment: The "crazy permission issues" exist in XP, not Windows 7.  Allowing any random program to write to \windows or \Program Files is crazy.  I prefer my PC without viruses, so I welcome our new UAC overlords.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the file in the system's temp directory, which you can find by calling `Path.GetTempPath()`.

In general, your program should only write to files in the user's Application Data (or temp) directories and only write registry keys in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  (This is true in *any* version of Windows)
If you follow these guidelines, you won't have any trouble in Windwos VIsta or 7.
You should never write information to places that are shared by multiple users.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: While the following will work, SLaks points out it's bad practice, and the temp file won't get cleaned up.

Try %HOMEPATH% - this is the environment variable for a users documents folder, and should work no matter which version if windows you use.

In other words where you used to have:

```
"c:\programfiles\programname\tempFileName"
```

use:

```
"%HOMEPATH%\tempFileName"
```

Comment: **Don't drop temp junk in My Documents**

Comment: This is BAD. You would make users folder a trash can.